# UV texture getting replaces by another image texture

Tags: modeling

hope everyone is well during these difficult times we're going through.

I have a logo which I want to map onto my model. I have marked the seams, even separated the mesh from the model, made a material, just for the specific location which I want to map my logo. But when I do the UV mapping, the UI text is getting replaced by the logo. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). You need to assign the new material to only the selected faces: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/

Comment: On a different note.. Sobibor? Hope it's not for a Polish client :)

Comment: Hello Jachym. 

Thank you for your reply. Yes it did work, I choose new faced and added a new material by duplicating the already existing one, just renamed it. And if this was client work, I think this would be a very unhappy customer lol. I was watching a move called escape from Sobibor when the idea came to me. Kind regards.